# CLR Debugger, ASP.NET -- how to increase timeout?

Tags: asp.net, exception, clr, timeout, debugging

I'm trying to debug a problem (exception being thrown) in an ASP.NET MVC program using the Microsoft CLR Debugger.  It works pretty well, except after a minute or two, the debugger gets detached (the web request times out or something?) and I can no longer inspect its state.

This is extremely frustrating.  How can I make the server/debugger (not sure who is at fault here) stay open until I tell it to stop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its on the IIS side, check this on how to configure/fix: http://vaultofthoughts.net/ASPNETDebuggerTimeoutInWindowsVista.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From the link:

In IIS 7 go to the Application Pools and select the Advanced Settings for the pool which you process runs in. In the Process Model section you can do one of two things;

- Set the Ping Enabled property to False. This will stop IIS checking to see if the worker process is still running and keep your process alive permanently (or until you stop your debugged process)
- If you prefer to allow IIS to continue the monitoring process then change the Ping Maximum Response Timeout value to something larger than 90 seconds (default value).